# SQLiteStatement.simpleQueryForLong() is behaving differently compared to what the documentation says

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm using the [`simpleQueryForLong()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html#simpleQueryForLong()) method in the following way:

```
mResuableStatment = DatabaseHandler.database.compileStatement(
        "SELECT MIN(timestamp) FROM " + TABLE_LOCAITON_LOGGING);

long oldestTimestamp = mResuableStatment.simpleQueryForLong();
```

- `timestamp` is the name of the column within the table `TABLE_LOCAITON_LOGGING`.
- the database is open for read and write at that point.

according to the documentation - if there are no rows at all, then this code suppose to throw [`SQLiteDoneException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDoneException.html), but what really happening is that when there are no rows - the `simpleQueryForLong()` **returns zero** (without throwing excpetion)

What was even more strange and unexpected, **when I actually wrap this code in try/catch block, it will throw `SQLiteDoneException` every time**, even when there are rows in the table:

```
try {
    long oldestTimestamp = mResuableStatment.simpleQueryForLong();
} catch (SQLiteDoneException e) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

This behavior was seen on Nexus 5, Galaxy Nexus, LG G2, HTC One X, all running Android KitKat.

I'm a little confused because this forced me not to use the try/catch block, since if it's used - the exception is always thrown regardless if there are rows or not, and vice versa to what the documentation says.

Seems like in every device I tested - without the try/catch block, when there are no columns - it returns zero.

Please help me to understand what is the right way, and what I'm doing wrong, or if simply the documentation is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think you'll find you have it the wrong way around.

```
select min(something) ...
```

will *never* return zero rows. It will either return the minimum value (if the table has rows) or `null` if the table has no rows. If your query was just `select something` when the table was empty, that could return zero rows so that might be worth testing.

I've tested this with SqlFiddle, entering the commands:

```
create table xyzzy(a int);
select a from xyzzy;
select min(a) from xyzzy;
```

The first `select` returns zero rows, the second returns one row with a `(null)` value.

So I don't believe it's the empty table causing the exception. It *may* be the attempted conversion of `(null)` into a long.

How you "fix" this depends entirely on what you want to use the data for. Relying on a null row being converted to zero may or may not be what you want. For example, if there *was* a zero timestamp in the table, you would not be able to tell the difference between that and an empty table.

That may be acceptable, it depends on your business requirements.

If you need to distinguish, I would run two queries. The first would return `count(*)` from the table. That's guaranteed to be a single row containing a *numeric* value (no nulls). If that's zero, it means the table is empty.

If non-zero, *then* do the `min(column_name)` and you'll get a single row with the minimum timestamp. If you get zero at that point, you know it's because the minimum timestamp was zero. Unless of course there's a NULL timestamp in there in which case you may have to do more checks. But I think that unlikely if you've structured your schema correctly.

Note that I wouldn't *normally* suggest this in a multi-user database since it may lead to race conditions. But I think it's probably okay since there should only be one "user" of this database, your application.

Comment: if so, then why the documentation says differently?, and how my code should look like to cover this case?

Comment: @Tal, it doesn't. It states that, if the query returns zero rows, it will throw the exception. What I'm saying is that `select min()` will _not_ return zero rows, it always returns one. `select x` may return zero rows but aggregate functions like `select min(x)` do not.

Comment: I don't understand one thing in your answer: I didn't say that it returns zero rows. I said it returns zero value. and as I told you - when I wrap it in try/catch - it always getting to the exception from some reason,  even when there are rows

Comment: @Tal, you stated that you expected the exception to be thrown if the table had no rows and that's where you're incorrect. The exception happens if the **query** has no rows. That query `min(x)` _never_ has no rows so the exception should never be thrown for that reason.

Comment: ok, so if I got it right, then I should not use the try/catch block, and if I get in reponse zero - It perfectly ok to assume that the table is empty?

Comment: @Tal, it depends entirely on what you're going to use it for. I'll add some options.